# Pass varilable in to [ngModel] angular -v2

Tags: angular

I want pass variable into `[ngModel]`. I am not sure about the syntax. Is it correct?

```
<select [ngModel]=this.audutModel (ngModelChange)="AddAdults($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select [ngModel]="audutModel" (ngModelChange)="AddAdults($event)">
```

The scope of the template is already `this` by default, therefore no need to add it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use it in template use without this,

```
<select [ngModel]="audutModel" (ngModelChange)="AddAdults($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `this` while referring any instance variable in case of Angular and always enclosed that `instance var` with double quotes.

Code is attached below

```
<select [ngModel]="audutModel" (ngModelChange)="AddAdults($event)">
```

Also here instead of using `[ngModel]` you can use `[(ngModel)]` and the details is attached below:

```
[ngModel]="val" is the syntax for one-way binding:

[(ngModel)]="val" is for two-way binding:
```